# LastModifiedDate is not getting updated for an entity using spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

// Entity model definition

```
@Builder.Default
@LastModifiedDate
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, name = "modified_dt", format = DateFormat.basic_date_time)
private Instant modifiedDate = Instant.now();
```

// update attribute call

```
protected void updateAttribute(String id, Document document) throws Exception {
    UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(id).withDocument(document).build();
    UpdateResponse updateResponse = operations.update(updateQuery, indexCoordinates());
    Result result = updateResponse.getResult();
    if (!result.equals(Result.UPDATED)) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need LastModifiedDate to be updated, your answer doesn't address that

Answer (score 0):

From version 7 the date format is different since *yyyy* has been replaced by *uuuu*, maybe it's related to this:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/migrate-to-java-time.html#java-time-migration-incompatible-date-formats

Also the Lombok annotation *@Builder.Default* won't work for parameterless constructors, so maybe it's also interfering.